# Passing const unsigned char arrays to a function

Tags: arrays, c

I thought I understood passing arrays to a function but the following code is proving I still have a way to go. Can somebody please explain the problem the compiler is warming off. I have reduced the code a minimum that still retains the errors.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned char uint8_t;
typedef unsigned int uint16_t;

const uint8_t sevensegment[18] = {  
  0x3F,   // 0
  0x06,   // 1
  0x5B,   // 2
  0x4F,   // 3
  0x66,   // 4
  0x6D,   // 5
  0x7D,   // 6
  0x07,   // 7
  0x7F,   // 8
  0x6F,   // 9
  0x77,   // A
  0x7C,   // B
  0x39,   // C
  0x5E,   // D
  0x79,   // E
  0x71,   // F
  0x00,   // space
  0x40,   // minus
};

void inttosevensegment(uint16_t num, uint8_t *display, uint8_t num_digits, const uint8_t *sevensegment)
// integer to seven segment display using ht16k33 driver
{
    uint8_t digit, lutindex;
    digit = num_digits-1;

    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < digit; i++) {
        display[i] = 0x00;
    }

    do {
        lutindex = num % 10 ;   //lookuptable index
        num = num / 10;
        display[ digit--] = sevensegment[lutindex];
   } while (num > 0);
}

int main(void)
{
    uint16_t intnumber = 345;
    uint8_t num_digits = 4;
    uint8_t display[4];
    inttosevensegment( intnumber, *display, num_digits, *sevensegment);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("buffer value = %X ", display[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The compiler errors

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:46:31: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘inttosevensegment’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  inttosevensegment( intnumber,*display,num_digits,*sevensegment);
                               ^
main.c:25:6: note: expected ‘uint8_t * {aka unsigned char *}’ but argument is of type ‘uint8_t {aka unsigned char}’
 void inttosevensegment( uint16_t num, uint8_t *display, uint8_t num_digits, const uint8_t *sevensegment)
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.c:46:51: warning: passing argument 4 of ‘inttosevensegment’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  inttosevensegment( intnumber,*display,num_digits,*sevensegment);
                                                   ^
main.c:25:6: note: expected ‘const uint8_t * {aka const unsigned char *}’ but argument is of type ‘uint8_t {aka const unsigned char}’
 void inttosevensegment( uint16_t num, uint8_t *display, uint8_t num_digits, const uint8_t *sevensegment)
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: `inttosevensegment( uint16_t num, uint8_t *display, ...` expects a pointer for the 2nd argument.  `inttosevensegment( intnumber,*display,...` is passing the first element of `display`, an `uint8_t`.  In C, code cannot pass an array to a function.  It can pass the address of the first array element though.  Try `inttosevensegment( intnumber,display,...` (no `*`).

Comment: `*display` is the same as `display[0]` which is a value of type `uint8_t`. So you are passing a `uint8_t` to a function that expects a `uint8_t` **pointer**. Compilers don't like that...

Comment: OT: Your code would be easier to read if it were "properly" indented. If the LUT is global, it needn't be passed as the 4th parameter to the function. Look into `sizeof` to replace some "magic numbers" (like '4'). (The compiler can measure things and will adapt when `uint8_t display[4];` becomes `uint8_t display[6];`

Comment: If the LUT is only used by this specific function, then consider moving it inside that function.